# VSCode not picking up ipykernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I'm trying to use vscode with jupyter via the python extension.  My pipfile looks like this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[packages]
opencv-python = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"

[dev-packages]
ipykernel = "*"
ipython = "*"
jupyter = "*"
```

To start the ipython interpreter i follow these steps:

- $ pipenv install
- $ pipenv shell
- $ code .
- using the Python: Select interpreter, i select the pipenv environment
- run code

when i got to the code block by pressing shift + enter, i see the errors:

[image]

Code block:

```
#%%
import cv2
```

I have also tried using all dependencies in the [packages] section, reinstalling my pipenv from scratch, and repeating the above process.

Always the same error, what am i missing?

```
$ code -v
1.41.1
26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
x64
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue do the following

1- remove python and fresh install new python the latest version has pip in it

2- open terminal as administrator and run the following command:

```
  pip install ipykernel --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: Thanks, install everything with pip3 and it worked. By the way, I didn't remove python, just following step 2 is enough.

Comment: Thanks , the 2nd command worked for me too. Also I had to create .ipynb file manually in VSCODE.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the python I had installed `python3.x`, but not `python3.x-dev`.

You can install this using:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-dev
```

Upon opening vscode i then hit `ctrl + shift + P` and selected `Python: Select Interpreter` and selected the virtual env containing `ipykernel`.

Comment: Yep, this did it for me too.  Everything was installed properly but I couldn't get the interpreter to run from VS Code.  Turns out I was pointed at the wrong interpreter!