# VS Code not registering that ipykernel is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to run Jupyter notebook files in VS Code but they fail to run due to the error:

> IPyKernel not installed into interpreter Python 3.8.5 64-bit

However as shown, I have installed the package.

[image]

I have checked similar questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100344/vscode-not-picking-up-ipykernel), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806475/vscode-not-detecting-ipykernel-verified-it-is-actually-installed), [three](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89242), [four](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9566)) but the solutions don't fix this issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

The solution for me was running this code in command prompt

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
```

The problem I think is related to a conflict with prompt-toolkit versions. Try it and let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade of 'traitlets' package caused this. You need to downgrade it from '5.0.0' to '4.3.3' version through this command:

```
python -m pip install 'traitlets==4.3.3' --force-reinstall
```

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13701#issuecomment-684994934) page for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install it:

```
pip install -U ipykernel
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the python interpreter of the environment in which you installed ipykerenel

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and spent the whole week trying to resolve it. What worked for me was installing the Jupyter dependencies for anaconda:

> conda install jupyter

I installed this in my base environment. After this VSCode worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, while trying to run notebook on vs-code. resorting to older version of jupyter notebook extension worked for me

Comment: None of the above answers worked for me :/

Comment: Switching to the "pre-release" version of the jupyter extension also solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to change the environment to the Conda Env instead of the suggested one. see picture below.

[image: coda environment]

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I reloaded my Jupyter Extension on VS code and that solved the issue.

I tried running `pip install --upgrade ipython` before and didn't work but it might have played its role when after reloading the extension

Answer (score 0):

This should work

- pip install -U ipykernel
- restart VS Code

Comment: This answer was already provided [here over two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979268/354577). Please don't repeat answers.