# ipykernel required error after installing it in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, conda

I get an error when running Jupyter Notebooks in VS code due to: ipykernel not installed in my_env

[image].

```
Running cells with 'Python 3.7.7 ('my_env')' requires ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment. 
Command: 'conda install -n my_env ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall'
```

But I already have installed ipykernel in both base and my_env, and have already installed a new kernel in my_env following.

```
(base) user@username folderA % pip show ipykernel
Name: ipykernel
Version: 6.9.1

(my_env) user@username folderA % pip show ipykernel
Name: ipykernel
Version: 6.9.1

(my_env) user@username folderA % python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_env
```

Also, when running the proposed `conda install -n my_env ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall` and reloading the window, the issue re-appears.

I have tried multiple solutions, like the proposed in [sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706013/vs-code-not-registering-that-ipykernel-is-installed), [sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed) and also [pip install --upgrade jupyter_client](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5014), but nothing works.

I am using macOS with M1 chip and conda 23.1.0
Let me know if I need to add additional details.

Comment: Is the kernel you selected consistent with the environment where the library is installed? If you run jupyter in a basic environment, will it work?

Comment: Managed to solve it. The problem was related to my installation of python in the environment. I re-started from scratch in a new environment and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was related to my installation of jupyter in the selected environment.

I re-started from scratch in a new environment, and followed the below steps **in order**:

```
conda create env -n env_name python=3.XX       
conda activate env_name               
conda install jupyter 
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=env_name
```