# Minimum package requirements to run a jupyter notebook in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Recently I keep running into problems with my python notebooks in vscode where vscode doesn't see the installed `ipykernel`. There are several posts on this issue with suggestions to update certain packages ([VSCode not picking up ipykernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100344/vscode-not-picking-up-ipykernel), [Python requires ipykernel to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997553/python-requires-ipykernel-to-be-installed), [vscode not detecting ipykernel, verified it is actually installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806475/vscode-not-detecting-ipykernel-verified-it-is-actually-installed), [Install ipykernel in vscode - ipynb (Jupyter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628465/install-ipykernel-in-vscode-ipynb-jupyter), ...)

This makes me wonder what the actual minimum requirements are. Different "offical" channels mention different dependencies:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment mentions `jupyter`
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Kernels-and-the-Jupyter-Extension#python-environments mentions `ipython` and `ipykernel`
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Installing-Jupyter mentions `jupyter` may be required.

Previously I only had

```bash
ipykernel
notebook
```

installed in the conda environment which worked just fine.

So what are the actual requirements to run jupyter notebooks in vscode? What are the needed packages with versions?

Comment: Here is the corresponding issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum requirement according to the ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14130 is

```bash
ipykernel
```

The `jupyter` package is only required when asked to install. It has to do with native zmq modules not working on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

[The official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) states that all you need  is install the [jupyter package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/) by command `pip install jupyter`, which includes notebook, qtconsole, and the IPython kernel.

At the same time, [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) in the vscode extension store is also necessary.

Comment: That is the same link / info that I posted above. My question is what the minimum requirements / versions are.